# Asking for advice on making my web-app mobile friendly and best practice to convert tables written in materialize to cards or something else on mobile

Tags: html, css, sass, materialize

I have a web-app with the front end using materializecss.com framework. It has quite a few data tables throughout.  My tables are using css from materialize and I really like the styling. The tables have between 5-8 columns and on mobile you first have to zoom in and then scroll over.

What I'm not sure about is what the best approach is to making this mobile friendly; I've been searching around for code that converts tables into cards and have found some for bootstrap cards but not for materialize. I don't want to hide columns.

I've tried my hand at a few solutions using media query's like: `@media only screen and (max-width: 992px)`... but I think materialize is overriding them because they are not working. I've tried to mark them `!important` or search through and modify the materialize css file but it is not working.

How bad would it be to create separate card elements and hide either the table or cards depending on screen size? It's mostly text data and links that are loading so I don't think it would significantly increase data transfer amount.

I'm not a pro at html/css/sass and even worse at javascript so any advice is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Adjusting your website in relation to the screen size is called `responsive`
Try looking for that in your research.

Using materialize gives you the option to the option to define a `row`and within that you can make columns and define their size. You can even define the size relative to the screen size.

Try looking into this: https://materializecss.com/grid.html
Materialize also has its own `(responsive) table` and `collection` structure that might be helpfull to you.

Also it might be helpfull to use `%` in your css instead of fixed `px`

If you this doe not solve your case, try looking into `flexbox` and `overflow`.

I hope I understood your problem correctly otherwise some code of yours would be really helpfull :)